# Accessing public variable without getter/setter using ONGL

Tags: jsp, scope, struts2, javabeans

How can access a public variable withouth getter and setter using OGNL in Struts2 ?

```java
public class Keys{
    public Integer count = 1; 
    public String all_type = "ALL";
    .....
}
```

```xml
<s:property value="Key.all_type" />
```

Comment: Expose them through your action, static method access doesn't work anymore

Comment: I import my class in the jsp `<%@ page import=" com.test.common.action.Keys,     com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext,
 java.util.*" %>`

Comment: ...... Don't :)

Comment: My problem is that the all_type is not a static attribute. If all_type was a static attribute I would have been able to access it using <s:property value="@com.test.common.action.AttributeKeys@all_type"/> but if the attribute is not static, the sentence doesn't work.

Comment: expose it through your action. Either make it public or use a getter, but from your action. Put it in an interface that your action implements, or in a base action that your action extends, and inherit it